# Efficient way to compute pair wise difference among the 1d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a specific problem.
I made up this code to compute difference of pairs of element in 1d array.

```
np.array([j-i for m, i in enumerate(X[:]) for j in X[m+1:]])
```

For example, for a input `X=np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])`, this code return `9*8/2=36` elements array which is:

```
np.array([1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,-2,-1,0,1,2,0,1,2,1,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1])
```

Although I understand that this code is inherently a O(n^2), my code takes a lot of time for larger array `X` (only n~400) and use a lot of memory. So I think double loop indexing is cause of this slow down and vectorization of this method may make it faster. Do you have any idea or know standard module to compute this?

Comment: how you got 9*8/2

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I meant that this code output an array with 36 elements when I input an array with 9 elements, since I choose pairs of elements in the array without replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (time) efficiently using broadcasting (which uses vectorization).  The solution for X of length 400 in instantaneous on my machine:

```
# X = np.random.rand(400)
X=np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
X = X.reshape(-1,1)
M = X.T - X
idx = np.triu_indices(len(X), k=1)
solution = M[idx]
array([ 1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -2, -1,
        0, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  1, -1,  0,  1, -2, -1,  0,  1,
        2,  1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute the difference between all possible pairs? That's inherently a O(n<sup>2</sup>).

You're always going to run into trouble at some point, but you can go a lot further by not keeping the entire square in memory, only lazily generating and using each value as you iterate.

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding me that this is inherently a O(n^2). I reflected it and refined my original question according your comment.